# Datepicker adding a month?

Tags: jquery, datepicker

Have an odd issue with the datepicker jumping a month on me. You can see what is happening in the jfiddle below.

Is this something I'm doing in code? It's happening in all of my browsers, IE, Firefox and Chrome.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Is it 0 based? So 0 = january and 11 = december?  This would be odd to me, but it's a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The months in a Date are 0 based. January is 0, December is 11.

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: What I don't get is that apparently the months are zero based and the days are not?

Comment: Gotta love the craziness and randomness that is Javascript.

Comment: I believe a lot of languages have the month 0 based. I know Java's calendar is that way too.